# JQuery multiselect box values issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a multiselect box that is a checkbox, here is my attempt to add the value to the existing selected values, remove the value from the exisiting selected values and set which overwrites all the selected values with the ones chosen. Im not getting results from these attempts and would appreciate a little guidance. thank you

```
     $('.add_button').click(function() {
        selected=$(this).val();

        id=$(this).attr('id');


        $('#opdots-bach-edit', 'option:selected', this).add();
    });

    $('.remove_button').click(function() {
        selected=$(this).val();

        id=$(this).attr('id');

        $('#opdots-bach-edit','option:selected', this).remove();

    });

    $('.set_button').click(function() {
        selected=$(this).val();

        id=$(this).attr('id');

        $('#opdots-bach-edit select.'+id).val(selected);
    });




    <input type="checkbox" name="employeeid[]" value="1870">
    <input type="checkbox" name="employeeid[]" value="1874">
    etc etc.

    then here are my div buttons

    echo '<div class="add_button" value="ssremployeeid[]">add</div>';
echo '<div class="remove_button" value="ssremployeeid[]">remove</div>';
echo '<div class="set_button" value="ssremployeeid[]">set</div>';
```

Comment: Im bit lost with your desc, could you provide html code?

Comment: @Squirtle how can a multiselect be a checkbox?  Isn't it a checkbox then?  Post your html code and a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Rooster here is the html added at the end. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Squirtle first off you need to declare selected and id as vars inside each of your click handling functions..ie var selected = ...  there may be more but you should post a jsfiddle, because as I read this it seems like there is likely more code that may be relevant.